# AdaptiveCard is shown without app icon/name in ms teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We are implementing search command for microsoft teams.

When `composeExtension/query` is invoked then bot returns list of attachments with previews that includes a Tap `Tap = new CardAction { Type = "invoke", Value...`. Like in this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/respond-to-search?tabs=dotnet#response-example

After this teams shows search result. When user clicks on any result then bot is invoked with `composeExtension/selectItem` and returns new AdaptiveCard as result. Then teams shows this card but without app icon/title. Also following error is logged in teams

```
0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114 2021-01-15T16:29:22.175Z AppsService: getInstalledAppForUser - Invalid appId specified
(anonymous) @ 0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114
(anonymous) @ 3.2-app.min-e6c3257.js:1
...
Uncaught (in promise) Invalid appId specified
```

But when user submit this card then it's shown correctly (with app icon/title and etc).
Can somebody help to fix this problem? Thanks in advance :)

---

This is the response for `composeExtension/selectItem`

```
{
  "composeExtension": {
    "attachments": [
      {
        "content": {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "body": [
            {
              "items": [
                {
                  "text": "Untitled task",
                  "type": "TextBlock"
                  ...
                }
              ],
              "separator": false,
              "type": "Container"
            }
            //...
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "url": "https://.....",
              "title": "View activity",
              "type": "Action.OpenUrl"
            }
          ],
          "version": "1.2"
        },
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "preview": {
          "content": {
            "title": "Preview"
          },
          "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero"
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "result",
    "attachmentLayout": "list"
  },
  "responseType": "composeExtension"
}
```

Comment: Hi @Denis Borovnev, Will repro, check internally and let you know ASAP.

Comment: Just to confirm, have you tried this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchBot.cs)

Comment: Hi @Mallipriya-MSFT. I have very similar code to this sample, but  [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/26e9964c21a166ff4c86f798e098e0ba3aef5e71/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchBot.cs#L79) I return AdaptiveCard instead of ThumbnailCard.   
I tried ThumbnailCard and with it everything works fine, app icon and title are shown and there is no errors

Comment: Also I'm using the same card for link unfurling and in this case it shown without errors and with app icon/title

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ad6eYR9iug9WfaRxn8akw1-pWHNo1Vke/view) you can see the diff between the cards from link unfurling and search

Comment: Ok, Will do a repro with adaptive card and let you know soon.

Comment: Hi @Denis Borovnev, while designing the adaptive card, Is the imageUrl/IconUrl is provided? Can you confirm on this.

Comment: Hi @Mallipriya-MSFT ! 
> `Is the imageUrl/IconUrl is provided `

Not sure what is it and how i can provide them.  

By the way I made a [repro](https://github.com/denisborovnev/BotBuilder-Samples/commit/24a3f21bf7d43462898445ebff1b1c254cd036d2) based on botbuilder - samples.

Comment: I tried with the code provided by you but couldn't repro the same. Can we discuss this over a call? Could you please write to us at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the Insights. We have raised a bug on the issue and it is being tracked internally.